# How do I determine an MVC controller/method name (request details) from within an API project / controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

If an exception occurs in MyApp.Api.Controllers.ItemController when I make the Http Request through RestSharp (or any HttpClient) calling GET: api/items/2, how can I know (for the purpose of debugging or logging) which MyApp.Web.Controller made the call to the api? (e.g. was it HomeController Foo() or AnotherController Bar()?

- MyApp.Web (.net core 3.1 MVC project)
- MyApp.Client (restsharp http client library)
- MyApp.Api (.net core 3.1 WebApi project)

I call api controllers from the MVC project through the rest client.

```
//MVC PROJECT
namespace MyApp.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Foo()
        {
            var item = _myAppClient.GetItem(2);
        }
    }

    public class AnotherController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Bar()
        {
            var item = _myAppClient.GetItem(2);
        }
    }
}

//REST CLIENT
public static Item GetItem(int id)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:6001");
    var request = new RestRequest("api/items/2", Method.GET);
    var item = client.Execute<Items>(request).Data;
    
    return item;
}

//API PROJECT
namespace MyApp.Api.Controllers
{
    public class ItemsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/items/2
        public Item Get(int id)
        {
            var item = new Item();
            throw new Exception("broken");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using public static Item GetItem(int id) to call APIs from any controller the simpliest way to know  controller name is  to add another input parameter like this

```
//REST CLIENT
public static Item GetItem(int id, string controllerName = string.Empty)
{
try()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:6001");
    var request = new RestRequest("api/items/2", Method.GET);
    var item = client.Execute<Items>(request).Data;
   } 
catch (Exception ex)
{
var errMessage= "Exception happens in Controller "+ controllerName + " except: "+ex.Message;
throw new Exception(errMsg, ex);
}
    return item;
}
```

and call it this way : var item = _myAppClient.GetItem(2, "controllerName + action name");

Answer (score 0):

Like @Serge said,in general, we pass `controllername` as a parameter to `Get` Action.

The following is an example of using `HttpClient` to call the `Ge`t method to pass the `Controllername` parameter:

HomeController:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    { 
        var controllerName = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        message.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
        var URL = "https://localhost:xxxx/api/items?id=1&controllername="+ controllerName;
        message.RequestUri = new Uri(URL);
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
        return View();
    }
```

Api Controller:

```
 public Item Get(int id,string controllername)
    {           
        var item = new Item();
        throw new Exception("broken");
    }
```

Result:
[image]